# source_sink 'library(process)' does not exist

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog

I wanted to install some 3rd-party software in swipl (version 7.5.5.; installed completely and without complaints from the github repo).

Now, I got the following error:

> ERROR: /usr/local/lib/swipl-7.5.5/library/prolog_pack.pl:52:
>     source_sink `library(process)' does not exist
>   Warning: /usr/local/lib/swipl-7.5.5/library/prolog_pack.pl:52:
>     Goal (directive) failed: prolog_pack:use_module(library(process))
>   ERROR: /usr/local/lib/swipl-7.5.5/library/prolog_pack.pl:56:
>     source_sink`library(filesex)' does not exist
>   Warning: /usr/local/lib/swipl-7.5.5/library/prolog_pack.pl:56:
>     Goal (directive) failed: prolog_pack:use_module(library(filesex))
>   ERROR: /usr/local/lib/swipl-7.5.5/library/prolog_pack.pl:57:
>     source_sink `library(xpath)' does not exist
>   Warning: /usr/local/lib/swipl-7.5.5/library/prolog_pack.pl:57:
>     Goal (directive) failed: prolog_pack:use_module(library(xpath))
>   ERROR: /usr/local/lib/swipl-7.5.5/library/prolog_pack.pl:59:
>     source_sink`library(uri)' does not exist
>   Warning: /usr/local/lib/swipl-7.5.5/library/prolog_pack.pl:59:
>     Goal (directive) failed: prolog_pack:use_module(library(uri))
>   ERROR: /usr/local/lib/swipl-7.5.5/library/prolog_pack.pl:60:
>     source_sink `library(http/http_open)' does not exist
>   Warning: /usr/local/lib/swipl-7.5.5/library/prolog_pack.pl:60:
>     Goal (directive) failed: prolog_pack:use_module(library(http/http_open))
>   ERROR: /usr/local/lib/swipl-7.5.5/library/prolog_pack.pl:61:
>     source_sink`library(http/http_client)' does not exist
>   Warning: /usr/local/lib/swipl-7.5.5/library/prolog_pack.pl:61:
>     Goal (directive) failed: prolog_pack:use_module(library(http/http_client),[])
>   ERROR: /usr/local/lib/swipl-7.5.5/library/prolog_pack.pl:1822:16: Syntax error: Operator expected
>   ERROR: Undefined procedure: prolog_pack:uri_components/2
>   ERROR: In:
>   ERROR:   [11] prolog_pack:uri_components(cplint,_928)
>   ERROR:   [10] prolog_pack:git_url(cplint,_960) at /usr/local/lib/swipl-7.5.5/library/prolog_pack.pl:1428
>   ERROR:    [9] prolog_pack:pack_default_options(cplint,_992,[],_996) at /usr/local/lib/swipl-7.5.5/library/prolog_pack.pl:467
>   ERROR:    [8] prolog_pack:pack_install(cplint) at /usr/local/lib/swipl-7.5.5/library/prolog_pack.pl:431
>   ERROR:    [7] 
>      Exception: (11) prolog_pack:uri_components(cplint, _1086) ? 
>   creep
>      Exception: (9) prolog_pack:pack_default_options(cplint, _1086, [], _1090) ? 
>   creep

Now, this isn't a problem of the particular 3rd-party software; I get the same error for two other packages, too.

What do I wrong? Is my install incomplete?

I appreciate any hints. Thx!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When building from source, note that you must take additional steps to build the **packages**, located in `swipl-devel/packages`.

From the `swipl-devel` directory, do:

```
$ cd packages
$ ./configure
$ make
$ sudo make install
```

See also the `README` file in `swipl-devel/packages` for more information about these packages.

For example, `library(process)` is part of the `clib` package that is installed only if you perform these steps or equivalent ones when building from source.

Answer (score 0):

@mat I have a similar situation, but I don't have a `swipl-devel` directory. Look at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72160025/i-cant-run-a-simple-prolog-file-pl).

Comment: this is not an answer